# How to set a script for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, css

I have used fullpage.js and in 3 sections i have implemented slickSlider.js 
and wrote a script to interact with its class's.

I copied over the code to a new section. Now i want to keep the code small so wrtiting seperate css and script for eack Slick is no good.

CSS i can combine and add new name eg. .div1, .div2, div3 {}

But the script i will have to rewrite and even more so. if i change the names.

Whats the best way to streamline this, or is 3 sets of script the only way?

With fullpage.js you can target each slide is there a way of creating if statments?

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
    if(index == 3 && anchorLink == 'golden-visa'){
        $('body.fp-viewing-slidefree').find('.fp-section').index();
            $.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(true, 'all'); 
            $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(true, 'all');
    }
```

P.S Im sure the code below can also be written better just learning the next step.

Thank guys

All the script that controls one instance of a Slick slider and its Class name is ".PlatformSlide":

```
//After Slider changes
$('.PlatformSlide').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
        if (currentSlide === 0) {
            $("#platformS1").click();
            $('.s22bt').removeClass('s22btActive');
            setTimeout(function(){
            },100);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.s22bt').addClass('s22btActive');
             },110);
        }   
        if (currentSlide === 1) {
            $("#platformS2").click();
            $('.s22bt').removeClass('s22btActive');
            setTimeout(function(){
            },100);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.s22bt').addClass('s22btActive');
             },110);
        }   
        if (currentSlide === 2) {
            $("#platformS3").click();
            $('.s22bt').removeClass('s22btActive');
            setTimeout(function(){
            },100);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.s22bt').addClass('s22btActive');
             },110);
        }   
});

// Slider Buttons
var feedP = $('.PlatformSlide');
$("#platformS1").click(function(e){ 
 e.preventDefault(); 
        slideIndex = $(this).attr('data-text'); 
        feedP.slick('slickGoTo', 0, true );
        $(".s22btbTopBox-left").removeClass("s22btbTopBox-leftActive");
        $(".TBoxL1").addClass("s22btbTopBox-leftActive");
        $(".s22btbTopBox-right").removeClass("s22btbTopBox-rightActive");
        $("#TBoxR1").addClass("s22btbTopBox-rightActive");
}); 

 var feedP = $('.PlatformSlide');
$("#platformS2").click(function(e){ 
 e.preventDefault(); 
 slideIndex = $(this).attr('data-text'); 
 feedP.slick('slickGoTo', 1, true ); 
 $(".s22btbTopBox-left").removeClass("s22btbTopBox-leftActive");
 $("#TBoxL2").addClass("s22btbTopBox-leftActive");
 $(".s22btbTopBox-right").removeClass("s22btbTopBox-rightActive");
 $("#TBoxR2").addClass("s22btbTopBox-rightActive");
});

 var feedP = $('.PlatformSlide');
$("#platformS3").click(function(e){ 
 e.preventDefault(); 
 slideIndex = $(this).attr('data-text'); 
 feedP.slick('slickGoTo', 2, true );
 $(".s22btbTopBox-left").removeClass("s22btbTopBox-leftActive");
 $("#TBoxL3").addClass("s22btbTopBox-leftActive");
 $(".s22btbTopBox-right").removeClass("s22btbTopBox-rightActive");
 $("#TBoxR3").addClass("s22btbTopBox-rightActive");
}); 


// Animate Platform Slide
$('.PlatformSlide').on('init', function(e, slick) {
    var $firstAnimatingElementsP = $('div.sbmt:first-child').find('[data-animation]');
    doAnimations($firstAnimatingElementsP);    
});

$('.PlatformSlide').on('beforeChange', function(e, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
                var $animatingElementsP = $('div.sbmt[data-slick-index="' + nextSlide + '"]').find('[data-animation]');
                doAnimations($animatingElementsP);              
});

function doAnimations(elements) {
    var animationEndEventsP = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
    elements.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $animationDelayP = $this.data('delay');
            var $animationTypeP = 'animated ' + $this.data('animation');
            $this.css({
                    'animation-delay': $animationDelayP,
                    '-webkit-animation-delay': $animationDelayP
            });
            $this.addClass($animationType).one(animationEndEventsP, function() {
                    $this.removeClass($animationTypeP);
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't need to rewrite the same code. In programming you should write for the general case and add parameters for differences. In principle, you're writing good code when you don't have to write the same thing more than once. So, most likely, you could make the same function work for each section without having to reference by ids but, instead, rely on the html structure of your sections which is probably similar. You seem to respect DRY in `doAnimations()`.

Comment: Hi, yes my html has become more structured due to using more script, just havnt crossed that mental vision of applying code in the way you said. More practice :)

Comment: Thanks for the "DRY" reading into it. Do animation had less varibles so was simple. Same thing should apply - https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/dont-repeat-yourself/

Answer (score 0):

I opted to do everything based on the already set id.  I would instead prefer to maybe have a data attribute with the number more easily available, but I don't know your html layout.

```
    $('.PlatformSlide').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
        $("#platformS" + (currendSlide + 1)).click()
        $('.s22bt').removeClass('s22btActive');
        setTimeout(function(){
        },100);
        setTimeout(function(){
                $('.s22bt').addClass('s22btActive');
         },110);
    }).on('init', function(e, slick) {
        var $firstAnimatingElementsP = $('div.sbmt:first-child').find('[data-animation]');
        doAnimations($firstAnimatingElementsP);    
    }).on('beforeChange', function(e, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        var $animatingElementsP = $('div.sbmt[data-slick-index="' + nextSlide + '"]').find('[data-animation]');
        doAnimations($animatingElementsP);              
    });

    var feedP = $('.PlatformSlide');
    $("#platformS1, #platformS2, #platformS3").click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        slideIndex = $(this).attr('data-text');
        var myId = $(this).attr("id");
        feedP.slick('slickGoTo', (parseInt(myId[myId.length-1]) - 1), true );
        $(".s22btbTopBox-left").removeClass("s22btbTopBox-leftActive");
        $(".TBoxL1").addClass("s22btbTopBox-leftActive");
        $(".s22btbTopBox-right").removeClass("s22btbTopBox-rightActive");
        $("#TBoxR1").addClass("s22btbTopBox-rightActive");
    }); 

    function doAnimations(elements) {
        var animationEndEventsP = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
        elements.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $animationDelayP = $this.data('delay');
            var $animationTypeP = 'animated ' + $this.data('animation');
            $this.css({
                'animation-delay': $animationDelayP,
                '-webkit-animation-delay': $animationDelayP
            });
            $this.addClass($animationType).one(animationEndEventsP, function() {
                $this.removeClass($animationTypeP);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time, love what you did. I added html, triggers dont work on any buttons now. PlatformS1 are buttons is it best to give new ids for each Slick? and slick a new name? (sorry added the html to your post)